# Python regex matching Unicode standard convention for code point value notation `U+xxxxxx`

Tags: python, regex

The regex below I have come up with:

```py
import re
pattern = r'\bU\+([0-9A-Fa-f]{4,6})\b'
```

does not exclude from matches all of the hexadecimal values larger than `10FFFF`.

Is it somehow possible to tweak the regex, or does such check need a function and can't be ( [Notational Conventions](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/appA.pdf) ) solved using a regex pattern?

Comment: I think writing some code is a cleaner and easier way to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to have at least four nibbles. There may be one or two nibbles before them, with separate cases for when the first nibble is `0` or `1`.

```
\bU\+((?:10|0?[0-9A-Fa-f])?[0-9A-Fa-f]{4})\b
```

Thanks to OP for corrections.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [unicode.org  Notational Conventions](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/appA.pdf) statement:

> > Appendix A, Notational Conventions:
> > In running text, an individual Unicode code point is expressed as U+n, where n is four to
> > six hexadecimal digits, using the digits 0–9 and uppercase letters A–F (for 10 through 15,
> > respectively). Leading zeros are omitted, unless the code point would have fewer than four
> > hexadecimal digits—for example, U+0001, U+0012, U+0123, U+1234, U+12345,
> > U+102345.

following Python regular expression covers the specification *and considers in addition to the rules for the notation also the upper limit of **10FFFF** for the Unicode code point values* :

#### `regex = r"\bU\+((?:10|[1-9A-F])?[0-9A-F]{4})\b"`

See the Python script below for the demonstration of usage of the regex pattern on a test string covering some edge cases:

```py
import re
regex = r"\bU\+((?:10|[1-9A-F])?[0-9A-F]{4})\b"

matchOnlyFirstColumn_testString = """\
U+10FFFF  U+11FFFF 
U+AFFFF   U+0AFFFF 
U+0041    U+41     
U+10123F  U+10123H 
U+12345   U+012345 
U+1FFFF   U+1ffff  
"""
matchiter = re.finditer(
                  regex, matchOnlyFirstColumn_testString, re.MULTILINE)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matchiter, start=1):
  print(f"Match {matchNum} at " +
        f"{match.start():3d}-{match.end():3d}: {match.group():8s}",
        end="  ")
  for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
    groupNum = groupNum + 1
    print( f"Group {groupNum} "+
           f"at {match.start(groupNum):3d}-{match.end(groupNum):3d}: "+
           f"{match.group(groupNum)}")
```

which outputs:

```
Match 1 at   0-  8: U+10FFFF  Group 1 at   2-  8: 10FFFF
Match 2 at  20- 27: U+AFFFF   Group 1 at  22- 27: AFFFF
Match 3 at  40- 46: U+0041    Group 1 at  42- 46: 0041
Match 4 at  60- 68: U+10123F  Group 1 at  62- 68: 10123F
Match 5 at  80- 87: U+12345   Group 1 at  82- 87: 12345
Match 6 at 100-107: U+1FFFF   Group 1 at 102-107: 1FFFF
```